# How to show everything in the table only if a value on a column on another table is equal to 1

Tags: mysql, sql, join, left-join, inner-join

Our users table has a domain and the domain table has a similar column named domain so I am able to join. But in our domain table there is a column suspended indicating whether the domain is suspended. How do I show all of my users on the users table if the domain.suspended on my domain table is 1?

```
SELECT *
FROM core.users,core.domain
WHERE core.domain.domain = core.users.domain;
```

Comment: Please add sample data and expected outcome. Your syntax is very strange and it's unclear how your tables look like.

Comment: Please ask 1 specific researched non-duplicate question. Please either ask about 1 bad definition/query/function with the obligatory [mre] & why you think it should return something else at the 1st subexpression that it doesn't give what you expect, justified by reference to authoritative documentation, or ask about your overall goal giving working parts you can do & ideally a [mre]. But please ask about the former 1st because misconceptions in the former will get in the way of understanding the latter. And bad code doesn't tell us what you wish it would do. [ask] [Help]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select * 
from core.users 
    inner join core.domain on core.domain.domain=core.users.domain 
where core.domain.suspended=1;
```